# Rails - call method on a field within a where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to extract the exchange rates from today(ie. the exchange rates have a `time` field of type `DateTime` and from this I want to extract the `day`). I want to do something like this:

```
ExchangeRates.where("time.day == ?", pred.time)
```

Is something of the kind possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database doesn't have a `DateTime` object in it that works like the Rails `DateTime` object. In order to query you'll have to send it something it understands, like a BETWEEN clause. You could do this:

```
ExchangeRates.where(time: pred.time.beginning_of_day..pred.time.end_of_day)
```

I'm assuming `pred` is a `DateTime` object